# FindBy statement in springs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My statement is:

```
findByCompanyIdAndIsDeletedAndFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrSecondNameContainingIgnoreCase
```

but `companyid` and `isdeleted` check is happing only for first name it is ignoring the second name. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: `findByCompanyIdAndIsDeletedAndFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrCompanyIdAndIsDeletedAndSecondNameContainingIgnoreCase` may work, but you can see that is bad practice... Have a look at [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice to give this much long name to the method, instead of this you can use [Specifications, QueryDSL, CriteriaQuery](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)